# Cocos2d-x : stop Previous action

Tags: cocos2d-x

how to stop the previous action in Cococs2d-x
my sprite have continous animation in init method
and recently i launched move action
i want to stop that move action only
that repeat animation still to be there only.

Answer (score 0):

For action we can set Tag using setTag method. When you don't want that action remove that using CCNode method "removeActionByTag"

Answer (score 0):

Hi bit late to the party.

Another solution is to call `stopAction(currentAction)` before calling `runAction(newAction)`. This enables you to stop `currentActionSave` before you start `newAction`. You will need to store the `currentAction` somehow, probably a member var, so you can later call `stopAction(currentAction)`.

Heres a code example:

**Dog.h**

```
#include "cocos2d.h"   

class Dog : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
public:
    ....

private:
    ....

    bool OnTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* /*event*/)

    cocos2d::Action* m_currentAction = nullptr;
};
```

**Dog.cpp**

```
#include "Dog.h"

....

bool Dog::OnTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* /*event*/)
{
    using namespace cocos2d;

    ....

    MoveTo* moveTo = MoveTo::create(time, pos);

    if (m_currentAction)
    {
        stopAction(m_currentAction);
    }

    m_currentAction = runAction(moveTo);

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.